# Allow only specific users to interact with the local session

Tags: linux, centos, pam, su

I have a Centos7 machine joined to an Active Directory domain.
the problem is that if I login to the Centos7 server I can interact within the session with any username from the Active Directory domain.

I can deny the access trough ssh unless the user is in a specific group, but I can not achieve the users to do

```
su - different_user
```

Where `different_user` is any user within the active directory.

I think this might be achievable using `pam` modules but do not know which one to use. I have tried the `pam_required.so` which makes all the users not being able to `su` to a different users account. Even to the ones which should have had access.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I can not achieve". Do the users get a password prompt? If not, what do they get instead? If they do and they enter a password, what happens? "can not achieve" is way too vague, sorry

Comment: "i can not achieve" - i can not deny the user to do "su - different_user" because anybody can do that once authenticated. of course i want to keep the option to run "su - allowed_user" available for the users

Answer (score 0):

If you want only certain users to be allowed as target for a `su` command, you could put the following in `/etc/pam.d/su`:

```
auth requisite pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=user sense=allow file=/etc/su-users
auth required pam_unix.so
```

now if you create a file `/etc/su-users` with one user per line, then only users listed in that file can be `su`'ed to.